# using folderBrowserDialog in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net

well,

lets i say i got a littel page on a big webiste. and i need you to select a folder using :

folderBrowserDialog

when you click on `button2` it will open a  folderBrowserDialog in asp.net(Not MVC.)

what can i do? lets take this code as a explne for it:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>
        Welcome.</h2>
    <p>
        In this page, you can Create\run bats files.</p>
    <p>

        &nbsp;</p>
    <p>

        &nbsp;
    <asp:button2 ID="Label1" runat="server" Height="25px" Text="Create">
    </asp:Label>
```

any one?

Comment: i have not head of a folderBrowserDialog .. is there something like that which supports all browsers?

Comment: i need to get a folder loction from a textbox, and folderbroserdialog give you that. it seems its not working on asp.net, got anything else?

Comment: There is no folderbrowserDialog in ASP.NET. You can only [select a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/den-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.aspx), but because of security restrictions you cannot get the full file-path from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get folderBrowserDialog to work but it would popup at the server, the client/browser would never see it so it would sit there forever waiting for input.

Comment: My MVC app installs as an application and runs a browser control in it. I am sending an ajax call to MVC from where I am opening up folderBrowserDialog . This is working when I debug . But After creating setup for this application and installing it folderBrowserDialog is not appearing at all .. Any thoughts on this . server and client all are installed in the same machine

Answer (score 0):

No, the .NET [FolderBrowseDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is not available for ASP.NET. If you want the user to select a folder (on the users local hard-drive) you probably need to use a Java-component.

If you need to let the user select a folder on the webserver, you can create your own FolderBrowseDialog look-a-like. :)

Comment: Yes!thats what i need. "if you need to let the user select a folder on the webserver, you can create your own FolderBrowseDialog look-a-like. :)" !! how can i do that?

Comment: You can achieve that with ASP.NET. But there are freeware controls available like http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/6f336b01-dce2-4d1c-9683-c4b59f698b4e/ But make sure that it is secure! (Make sure 'private' directories are not shown)

Comment: What do you mean with 'any other way?' ?

Comment: I think those are pretty much your only options: 1. write it yourself 2. use a 3rd party user control :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use things like SWF upload to provide the user with a user friendly good looking upload experience. It also has the possibility to upload multiple files / a folder. 
Check out : http://swfupload.org/project/asp_net

Or you can use a plain old: 
form with method="post"
attribute enctype="multipart/form-data"
and a field like this:
input type="file" name="somename" size="chars"