# Asp.net | STAThread attribute error

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net, razor

I want to open a FolderBrowseDialog on button click in MVC razor(VB) syntax.

For that i am calling a jquery function on "onclick" button event and through that function i am making a Post request to function in my controller that contains code to show FolderBrowseDialog.

here is my code.

Html:

```
<input type="button" class="btn" value="browse" onclick="SelectFolder()"/>
```

jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function SelectFolder()
{
    $.post("@Url.Action("FolderPicker", "Home")", function () {
            alert('sdd');
        },function(ex){
            alert("Error occured in AJAX");  
    });
}


</script>
```

Controller.. vb code to show FolderBrowserDialog.

```
<STAThreadAttribute()>
Sub FolderPicker()
    Dim browser As FolderBrowserDialog = New FolderBrowserDialog()
    browser.Description = "Select Folder"
    browser.ShowNewFolderButton = False
    browser.RootFolder = Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop
    Dim result As DialogResult = browser.ShowDialog()

    If result = DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim selectedPath As String = browser.SelectedPath
    End If


End Sub
```

At
    Dim result As DialogResult = browser.ShowDialog()
i am getting exception

```
Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE  

calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute  

marked on it. This exception is only raised if a debugger is attached to the  

process.
```

I also included STATreadAttribute() and STATread() but still i get this error.

Am i missing some thing?
Is there any other way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FolderBrowseDialog is not available in ASP.NET/MVC.
You can read some more stuff [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6506090/using-folderbrowserdialog-in-asp-net).

Answer (score 0):

the STATreadAttribute  should be on the Main function of your program,meaning the entry point of the program

Comment: i am making a web application so it do not have any main method.

Comment: try to set the AspCompat attribute on
the page directive to true <%@ Page AspCompat="true" %>